# How to deny Delete for a single Row in a Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008.

I need to DENY any delete operations on a specific ROW in a Table.

I would like to know how can implement this feature at DB level.

Please provide a sample of T-SQL. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INSTEAD OF DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208.aspx) trigger and ROLLBACK TRAN. Here is a [good article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TriggersSqlServer.aspx) on this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a trigger that throws an exception if the deleted row is your specific row.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment, please could you provide me a sample of code? i'm pretty new at sql thanks for your help!